# How does dual PSU setup work?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, power

This just an academical question, I am not looking to buy anything, I would just like to understand how it works.

There is a number of dual PSU servers, eg. they have 2 power supplies, each running on 50% and if one of them die, the system keep running just fine from one that start running on 100% (power consumption). I would like to know how is that done from technical point of view.

I suppose there is only 1 power input on motherboard and each device (hard drives) also have only 1 input for cable, so I suppose there is some special cable that link these both PSU units together? Something like this: http://www.frozencpu.com/products/5637/ so my questions are

- Does this require a special PSU unit that is designed to run in parallel with other PSU?
- Is there such a cable to provide power input for devices like hard drives as well?

Is there any significant difference in design when I compare these "home made" solutions where such a cable is used, compared to solutions used in retail servers, such as this HP PSU module http://h30094.www3.hp.com/product.aspx?sku=11138373&mfg_part=744689-B21&pagemode=ca - I suppose it works same from technical point of view, just there is no need for special cables etc?

Some schematics would be nice :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. Its worth considering that the PSUs on a proper server are *redundant* - they are designed to failover one from another. The motherboards probably have two inputs (or there's a power distribution board of some sort). In short the systems are designed *from the ground up* to run two PSUs and switch between them with no interruption.

Your adaptor, if you notice, has 2 headers that are fully wired up and one with *two* cables. So happens that an ATX PSU will power up if the green and black cables are shorted (and ideally there's a load). You'd want this if for some reason you didn't have enough power in your current PSU (or needed many more connectors) and wanted a second PSU to power other things. Some bitcoin miners use stuff like this for additional graphics cards and so on. I sometimes used to just short out those two leads on a cheap PSU when I needed to power something for testing quickly.

If your primary PSU fails with the frozencpu adaptor, the whole system goes down. A proper redundant PSU will probably solder on, oblivious to the loss of its companion, while your motherboards throws you an error about how the other PSU had the audacity to die. You can then *hotswap* that PSU.

Comment: TBH I don't think server boards have multiple power inputs, I didn't find one that had. On other hand I managed to find some server PSU (these are sometimes called RPS - redundant power supplies) they are boxes of various sizes, either ATX, or for rack server case size, that contains hot-swappable modules, which are actually the real power supplies. Each of these modules is connected to some central board which distributes the power further. So there are same output cables as for any regular PSU, they are just connected to this "central board" which is inside of RPS.

Comment: See http://www.ebay.com/itm/Used-Ampower-TOP-300SSR-300W-Redundant-ATX-Power-Supply-w-2-Modules-/141377342213?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item20eabf0b05

Comment: So it looks that this RPS can be installed in any computer (it has size of regular PSU and same cables), no matter if it's "build from the ground up" to run multiple PSU's

Comment: My guess is the necessary circuitry is built into the 'shell' that holds the two smaller PSUs. With proper servers, the power supplies slide into a backplane. Implimentation details aside, a redundant power supply is *designed* from the ground up for redundancy. One does not merely wire up and duct tape two normal PSUs and expect redundancy. I DO believe there's a product out there that allows it,